# Cosine similarity in PHP

Tags: php, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the cosine similarity between 1 (ID1) and 3 (ID1) in PHP. 
formula would be something like this:

```
similarity = (1.1 * 3.1 + 1.4 * 3.4)/(((1.1)^2+(1.3)^2+(1.4)^2)^0.5)(((3.1)^2+(3.4)^2)^0.5) = (4*4+8*4)/(((16+16+64)^0.5)(16+16)^0.5))
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID1    ID2    Value  
1      1       4     
1      3       4     
1      4       8     
3      1       4     
3      4       4    
4      1       8     
4      3       4
```

Is there any algorithm for calculating a cosine similarity in PHP for this?

Comment: Algorithms should be language-agnostic. Do you mean you're looking for a PHP implementation?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a PHP implementation

Answer (score 4):

Similarity between vectors A and B can be seen as the dot product between A and B normalized by dividing it by the product of the two norms.

The dot product in PHP can be written without for cycles:

```
$dot_product=array_sum(array_map(create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a * $b;'), $a1, $a2));
```

so first create the function:

```
function dotp($arr1, $arr2){
     return array_sum(array_map(create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a * $b;'), $arr1, $arr2));
}
```

now the cosine similarity is

```
$similarity=dotp($id1,$id2)/sqrt(dotp($id1,$id1)*dotp($id2,$id2))
```

Comment: But I will need a for loop if I want to calculate similarity between each ID1 values i.e. if I want to calculate similarity between 3 and 4, 1 and 4 as well.

Comment: Can you make an example? You mean you have more than two arrays (e.g.: $id1, $id2, $id3... $idN) and want to calculate the N*(N-1)/2 similarities between all the possible pairs?

Comment: I just have 2 arrays but I need to find the similarity between each ID1 element. ID2 elements are part of ID1, as you can see for same value of ID1 I have more than 1 value of ID2. From the example given above I need to find similarity between 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 3 and 4.